# Java code transformed to what

Tags: java, compilation

As example the java-compiler transforms `string1 + string2` into

```
    new StringBuilder(string).append(string).toString();
```

or an `enum` generates a `class with final static constants`.

Is there any program where I can see in what the code will be transformed?

I tried to decompile the .class files but it was still the same code.

Comment: It's part of java's abstractions not to know these things. But if you insist, just read the optimization part of the java compiler?

Comment: nice to know (that I shouldn't know it)! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java source code is transformed into byte code.  Using the `javap` command via the command line will allow you to view generated bytecode.

```
javap -c package.name.ClassName
```